# Meta Problem Issue - doesnt scale for Iphones

Tags: html, css, image, viewport

I'm all new to this
I'm learning how to code and trying to make sure that the website is looking good on desktop and on the iPhone but doesn't seem like the viewport works and not sure what to change.
Any help would be appreciated.

Website is:
https://danielfww.github.io/Stuff/

and the code for meta I put is;

```
<!Doctype>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 minimum-scale=1, userscalable="no" name="viewport">
```

I'm thinking maybe image is the problem but not sure myself
I changed meta several times but I don't see any difference.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use this code in your CSS file:
`h1 { width:100%; }`
Let me know if you are facing an issue.

Thank you.

Comment: How does this solve the question? `h1`'s are block elements by default, meaning they already take up 100% of the width - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/27gptLf0/)